# Erro na implementação de classe em C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, header

Eu estou tentando resolver um erro desde ontem, mas até agora não sei oque estou fazendo de errado ao fazer implementação de uma classe em C++.

Eu coloquei a classe com os protótipos num arquivo de extensão .h (header) e os métodos em um de mesmo nome só que de extensão .cpp,
Eu fiz o mais simples possível para saber onde está o erro mas até agora não consegui resolver:

**teste.h**

```
#ifndef TESTE_H
#define TESTE_H


class Teste {
    public:
        void mostra();
};


#endif
```

**teste.cpp**

```
#include "teste.h"
#include <iostream>


void Teste::mostra() {
    std::cout << "Isso é um Teste\n";
}
```

**main.cpp** (Acho que o erro não está aqui, mas coloquei só pra garantir)

```
#include "teste.h"


int main() {
    Teste *test = new Teste;
    test->mostra();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Erro:

```
undefined reference to `Teste::mostra()'
clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou: https://replit.com/@acwoss/DifferentLeanDeskscan#main.cpp

Comment: O problema não é do código, é na forma que você está compilando e gerando o executável. O código do módulo teste.cpp não está sendo linkado no executável final. Adicione os comandos que você está usando para compilar à pergunta, para dar uma resposta final.

Answer (score -1):

Veja essa execução em uma pasta só com esses arquivos que você listou, no Windows

```
C: Teste> >cl /EHsc main.cpp teste.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30037 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
teste.cpp
Generating Code...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30037.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
teste.obj

C: Teste> >main
Isso e um Teste

C: Teste> >dir
 O volume na unidade C não tem nome.
 O Número de Série do Volume é 7E52-1BF2

 Pasta de C: Teste> 

16/07/2021  01:07    <DIR>          .
16/07/2021  01:07    <DIR>          ..
16/07/2021  01:03               109 main.cpp
16/07/2021  01:08           175.104 main.exe
16/07/2021  01:08               755 main.obj
16/07/2021  01:03               107 Teste.cpp
16/07/2021  01:03                96 Teste.h
16/07/2021  01:08            64.041 teste.obj
               6 arquivo(s)        240.212 bytes
```

Não sei em que ambiente está usando isso mas por exemplo usando gcc no linux pode rodar `g++ -o tst main.cpp teste.cpp` e o compilador vai criar o executável `tst`. Veja acima que no Windows criou `main.exe`.

Se está usando um IDE cada IDE tem o seu jeito de fazer essas coisas, mas em geral basta criar um projeto, inserir `main.cpp` e criar a classe `Teste`.